# Como criar exceções obrigatórias em C#?

Tags: c#, exceção

Há alguma forma de fazer com que um método lance uma exceção que deve obrigatoriamente ser tratada, quando o método for invocado?

Utilizei o `throw new Exception("mensagem de erro")` mas o tratamento ainda fica opcional ao invocar o método.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Por sorte não tem. Isto que você quer é chamado de *checked exception* e tem uma série de problemas que não vem ao caso agora. Além do que se existisse as pessoas abusariam. Já não basta as pessoas acharem que deve lançar e capturar `Exception`?

A forma usada é documentar e rezar. Mas você pode criar uma ferramenta de análise estática que verifique isto no código. Com o novo [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) fazer uma ficou bem mais fácil e dá para integrar ao Visual Studio. Não é tão simples, depende do programador usar a ferramenta, mas ajuda.

Criar testes ajudam bastante. O Visual Studio pode criar muitos testes de forma automática para você através do Smart Unit Tests, incluindo testes que geram exceções para ver se você cuidou de tudo. É uma solução para quem programa desta forma.

Um detalhe importante é que são relativamente raras as situações em que isto realmente é necessário. Em geral os métodos devem poder funcionar independentemente da captura da exceção ou devem quebrar mesmo.

[Talvez os geradores de código ajudem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Realmente a pergunta veio da minha experiência com JAVA e como agora estava estudando exceptions em C# e percebi essa diferença de funcionamento eu preferi acabar com a dúvida antes de passar pra frente na linguagem. Obrigado pelo feedback.

Comment: Está fazendo certinho. Em Java há enorme abuso das exceções e mais ainda das checadas. É uma cultura da linguagem. Em C#, pelo menos entre os bons programadores, o seu uso é mais controlado. Se opta por elas quando a situação realmente é excepcional. Falo muito sobre o assunto aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:101+[exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o]

Answer (score 2):

Ao contrário do Java, não, isto não é possível.

Segue uma leitura para ler um pouco sobre os motivos disto (em inglês):

[The Trouble with Checked Exceptions](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Isso é algo próprio do copilador Java, que obriga que determinadas exceções sejam tratadas. Isso fica declarado na assinatura do método com a declaração `throws`, como mostrado abaixo:

```
public void drinkCoffee(CoffeeCup cup) throws
        TooColdException, TooHotException {
        int temperature = cup.getTemperature();
        if (temperature <= tooCold) {
            throw new TooColdException();
        }
        else if (temperature >= tooHot) {
            throw new TooHotException();
        }
        //...
    }
```

Bem, já o c# não obriga que você trate as exceções. Porém quando você programa, é fácil imaginar coisas que podem gerar exceções. E elas devem ser tratadas sempre, principalmente se você está desenvolvendo uma solução mais comercial, que vai entrar em produção, ou algo voltado para usuários em geral.

Lembre-se que tratar exceções e minimizá-las ao máximo é uma boa prática de programação, mesmo que a linguagem deixe isso como algo opcional. Quando você faz isso, você torna seu código mais seguro e evitará diversos problemas com reclamações de clientes no futuro.

Comment: Muito pelo contrário, exceções devem ser tratadas somente quando realmente precisam, senão, não trate, Isto é um dos maiores mitos da programação. Tratar exceção sem necessidade é uma péssima prática. A linguagem deixa opcional porque deve ser opcional. Infelizmente não tem uma forma de impedir a captura indevida da exceção. Quem faz isto frequentemente deixa o código menos confiável porque apenas esconde o problema quando não pode fazer nada útil e especializado.

Comment: Tratar significa minimizar o impacto que as exceções podem ter em sua aplicação, não escondê-la. As vezes com simples validações você pode evitar que diversas exceções ocorram. Por isso falei de tratar e minimizar.

Comment: Isto não é tratar exceção como você disse, isto é evitar que ela aconteça. Sim isto está certo, mas a sua resposta incentiva o tempo todo o tratamento. Só a parte da minimização é que está certa e quase escondida e está ambíguo do jeito que está escrito. Tratar e minimizar são coisas antagônicas.