# Compilador Roslyn - O que é, e porque foi criado?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, compilação, .net-compiler-platform

O que é o compilador Roslyn?

Esse é o compilador padrão do Visual Studio?

É open source? Por que fizeram isso?

Só serve para o C# ou para outras linguagens também?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671

Comment: Não entendi os negativos, a pergunta é pertinente. Não tem nada em português fácil de achar, consolidado, verificado por bons profissionais *experts* no assunto. Não vi falta de pesquisa, vi utilidade, está clara. O máximo que tem várias perguntas interligadas. Mas acho que é melhor assim do que se fizesse 5 perguntas separadas. No fundo é uma só com desdobramentos.

Comment: +1. Eu também quero saber o que é o _Compilador  Roslyn_. E por fazer parte da comunidade é que posso contemplar a pergunta :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Agora ele chama [.NET Compiler Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform). É uma plataforma de compilação como serviço, então você tem uma biblioteca extremamente desacoplada com as diversas funcionalidades do compilador disponíveis para serem chamadas conforme a necessidade. O compilador da linguagem como conhecemos é apenas um dos consumidores desta plataforma.

É o compilador padrão do C# 6 e está junto ao ([finado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101)) .NET 4.x , [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) e [Visual Studio 2015](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101) e posteriores. Parte dele estava sendo aproveitado para o Mono (que para todos efeitos [morreu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101)).

Usa licença MIT e é [100% *open source*](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), mais livre que GPL. É escrito em C#. Boa parte do compilador VB.NET é escrito em VB.NET.

Você pode fazer o que quiser com o código exceto dizer que foi você que fez tudo isto, ou seja, não pode tomar a propriedade dele, mas o uso fica liberado para qualquer situação.

Ele é usado para C# e VB.NET. Só. Mas sua infraestrutura pode ser usada para facilitar o trabalho de outras linguagens. É um compilador "estado da arte".

Ele foi criado para provar que C# é uma linguagem boa pra caramba e dá para fazer qualquer coisa com ótimo desempenho :)

Claro que tem objetivos mais importantes, apesar do anterior ser uma verdade velada:

- Prover infraestrutura para outras ferramentas que precisam *parsear* código em C# e VB.NET.
- Eliminar os diversos serviços de compilação parcial que a Microsoft e terceiros tinham no IDE (navegação, *refactoring*, auxiliadores, formatadores, etc.), diversos *frameworks* (ASP.NET, EF, LINQ, etc.), analisadores de código (FXCop), geradores de código, [Semantic Diff](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/SemanticDiff.html), etc. e gerar oportunidades para outras ferramentas surgirem com baixa barreira de entrada.
- Permitir que aplicações consumam seus serviços (DSLs, *business rule engine*, *workflow*, *plugins*, etc.).
- Facilitar a criação de mecanismos de *script* e REPL (interpretação).
- Oficialmente não se fala muito nisto mas é ótimo para facilitar a [metaprogramação](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) e a [programação orientada a aspectos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).
- Fornecer uma API consistente para acesso fácil ao código.
- Facilitar as mudanças no compilador em uma linguagem mais segura e mais fácil que o C++ (linguagem do compilador original). Agora dá para experimentar mais facilmente (não só dentro da Microsoft), e dá para implementar novas funcionalidades mais rapidamente e com custo mais baixo.
- Facilitar a escrita de código paralelo usando a [TPL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para aproveitar melhor os diversos processadores existentes hoje. Era quase impossível fazer isto no código antigo, não só pelo C++ não ajudar tanto, mas também porque o compilador antigo foi mal planejado ou pelo menos não pensado para isto.
- Consertar o monte de erro que fizeram no compilador original e montar uma arquitetura mais robusta e flexível. Tiveram a oportunidade de enxergar melhor certos aspectos do processo de compilação.
- Não era objetivo original mas a abertura permitiu receber contribuições, mais gente verificando problemas no código.
- Ter uma única infraestrutura para atender mais de uma linguagem que tem quase a mesma semântica. Assim as alterações feitas para C# ficam gratuitas ou muito baratas de implementar em VB.NET e vice-versa.

---

- [Informações importantes introdutórias](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Roslyn%20Overview).
- Quer saber mais? [Ouça de um dos autores do projeto](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-816T?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).