# Converter string em função

Tags: c#

Qual é a melhor maneira de fazer uma conversão de string para void sem complicações.

Tentei utilizar este código mas aparece `NullException`

```
        private void Mainform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   var method = "public void MSG(object o){ MessageBox.Show(o); }";
            method.GetType().GetMethod("MSG").Invoke("MSG", new object[] { "ZZZ" }); //Exception Aqui
        }
```

Mas ele retorna o seguinte:

[image: NullException]

No Local (VS2012) aparece o seguinte:
[image: Locals]

Meu caso é o seguinte. Quero desenvolver um launcher de um jogo, mas esse launcher deve ser feito baseado em ações `SortedDictionary<int, Acion>` onde int é o id da ação e Action é a ação baseada num método em string que seja convertido para o mesmo.

E em um XML estaria todas as ações detalhadas:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<!-- DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE OR ALL OF THE FUNCTIONS EVEN BECOME INVALID AND UNSTABLE. IN THE CASE MAY RESULT IN SYSTEM FAILURE, AMONG ALL OTHER ERRORS IN COMMON. -->
<rels>
  <rel id="0" exec="play_button" />
  <rel id="1" exec="reg_button" />

  <rel id="2" exec="home_button" />
  <rel id="3" exec="clan_button" />
  <rel id="4" exec="shop_button" />
  <rel id="5" exec="forum_button" />
</rels>
```

> Onde rel esta declarando a nova ação, id é o id em int e exec informa ao SortedDictionary quem que deve executar a função.

E quando ele prepara para executar a ação:

```
public async void executar_acao(int id){await Task.Run(lista_de_acoes[id]);
```

Comment: A melhor forma é não fazer. Em geral as pessoas tentam fazer isto por motivos errados. Se realmente precisar fazer isto, então é melhor montar um sistema de *script*. O que é bem mais fácil agora com o novo [.Net Compiler Platform](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este é o jeito incrivelmente errado de fazer o que você quer. Você quer definir uma função em tempo de execução, o que é interessante, mas não é por `String` que você deve fazer isto.

O correto é usar [*delegates*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/900fyy8e.aspx). O uso é assim:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public delegate void MeuTipoDeDelegate(object o);

    public static void Main()
    {
        MeuTipoDeDelegate teste = delegate(object o) {
            Console.WriteLine(o);
        };

        String umaStringQualquer = "Oi, eu sou uma String";
        teste(umaStringQualquer);
    }
}
```

[Fiz um Fiddle pra você demonstrando isso](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cTIJfS). Como no seu caso você quer definir um dicionário de ações, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
public delegate void MinhaAcao(object o);
public SortedDictionary<int, MinhaAcao> dicionarioTeste;
```

Aí você define em algum lugar do seu código o *delegate* de cada ação:

```
MinhaAcao acaoDePlay = delegate(object o) 
{
    /* Escreva aqui a função normalmente */
};

dicionarioTeste.Add(0, acaoDePlay);
```

Comment: Sim. funcionou, mas agora como eu faço para o aplicativo carregar essa dll automaticamente na inicialização?

Comment: por que a minha acaoDePlay deve estar em uma biblioteca externa.

Comment: irá funcionar como se fosse "plugins"

Comment: Sim, a ideia é a mesma. Você pode definir seus *delegates* em plugins e apenas chamá-los na aplicação principal.

Comment: Pra carregar a DLL em tempo de execução, vou te pedir outra pergunta.