# É possível habilitar os light bulbs no Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

É possível usar [light bulbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn872466.aspx) no Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 5 ?

Como habilitar o recurso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diretamente pelo VS não porque é um recurso novo. Você pode ter efeito semelhante e até com mais opções utilizando o [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Obviamente esta não é a única extensão e você também pode desenvolver uma extensão que faça isto. Claro que sem o [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) fica mais difícil.

Comment: Existe alguma alternativa gratuita ao Resharper?

Comment: Igual não, tem coisas muito simples que não chega aos pés dele. Nem na sola :D