# Existe algum algoritmo livre para verificar sintaxe C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sintaxe

Estou criando um pequeno editor de texto que possui código C#. Tem alguma maneira de dentro do próprio programa, independentemente, verificar se a sintaxe está correta?

Obs.: Eu não estou usando C# para fazer o editor de texto. Estou atrás apenas de um algoritmo de sintaxe. Pode ser em qualquer linguagem, é fácil de converter.

Meu objetivo não é achar uma biblioteca que faz tudo, mas um algoritmo aberto. Me parece que algo relacionado a BNF pode me ajudar.

Comment: O editor vai manipular código C#? Ele precisa verificar a sintaxe de C#?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo, só C# .

Comment: Depois desta edição parece que a pergunta ficou pior. Está bem confuso o que quer. Talvez o que quer não exista. Talvez nem faça sentido. Tente esclarecer melhor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu diria que não existe nada minimamente próximo do que o [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) pode fazer. Ele pode parecer complexo à primeira vista, mas a tarefa que está querendo fazer é complexa. E na verdade a API dele é bem fácil de usar para quem tem uma noção do assunto. Ele foi escrito para facilitar muito a vida de quem vai produzir ferramentas que precisam analisar código C# e VB.NET de alguma forma. Ele foi escrito para ser bem modular, você usa só o que precisa.

Além dele ter sido feito para se integrar com ferramentas como editores de código, ele é a única forma de garantir que evoluções da linguagem estarão automaticamente contempladas.

Você pode até achar soluções mais simples, mas serão bem ruins. Eu nem perderia tempo.

O Visual Studio trocou todos seus códigos próprios por esta solução.

Comment: Quem negativou poderia explicar o que tem de errado na resposta. Conhece algo melhor que isto para usar? Poste a resposta.