# Herança classe Object

Tags: java, c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Como o compilador faz para implicitamente todas as classes herdarem de `object`?

Esse é um comportamento adotado em linguagens como o C#, Java e outras.

```
public class Funcionario 
{

}

public class Funcionario : Object
{

}
```

O exemplo acima é redundante. Mas como o compilador  sabe que todas as classes criadas devem assumir esse padrão? Existe a possibilidade do programador forçar o compilador a implementar tal comportamento? Talvez até mesmo forçando a herança de outras classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Mas como o compilador sabe que todas as classes criadas devem assumir esse padrão?

É o padrão que foi criado. Durante o desenvolvimento das linguagens, definiu-se que, no topo hierarquico de herança, deveria haver uma super classe em comum.

> Existe a possibilidade do programador forçar o compilador a implementar tal comportamento? Talvez até mesmo forçando a herança de outras classes?

Não (que eu saiba). Seria ilógico ao contrário, pois o compilador não saberia como tratar o artefato.
Pode se forçar a herança que quiser, mas sempre terá como primeira herança, a de `Object`.

Answer (score 7):

Não tem como o programador evitar a herança de `Object` na linguagem, e até onde eu sei, nem mesmo em um nível mais baixo.

Não tem segredo fazer isso. Toda classe que não tem outra herança, e o compilador coloca lá a herança de `Object`. Ele faz a [análise sintática e semântica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101) do que está escrito e decide o que fazer. O compilador sabe já que um programador o programou assim.

Quando há a herança de outra classe, ele não precisa fazer isso porque, já que todas classes herdam de `Object`, é certo que a herança de outra classe herda fará esta herdar de `Object` por hierarquia.

Comment: Desculpe, amigo, não tinha visto a sua resposta antes de colocar a minha ^^.

Comment: @bigwon, agradeço a resposta. Creio que a análise sintática e semântica são o ponto chave ao meu questionamento. É possível simular tal comportamento via C# ? Por exemplo, crio um framework e desejo que todas as classes herdem de object2...

Comment: @Pedro não tem como obrigar em condições normais. Claro que pode alterar o [compilador do C#](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) ou fazer alguma ferramenta extra para "garantir isso", desde que use a ferramenta ou sua versão do compilador. Mas não é recomendado.

Comment: @Pedro em linguagens compiladas não é possível sem que o próprio compilador suporte esta operação, que não é o caso do C# ou do Java. Mas dá para fazer algumas ganbiarras bem interessantes em algumas linguagens interpretadas (-ex. Ruby)