# Como compilar um software através de um site?

Tags: php, c#, compiladores

Estou a fazer um site em que a pessoa pode criar um software através do mesmo. Mas minha dúvida é: Como fazer isso de forma automatizada?

A proposta seria que o software fosse feito em WPF e o código fosse sendo customizado a partir de um monte de `switch-case` e `if-else` e depois ele era compilado no servidor e o cliente poderia baixar o executável.

- Existe alguma forma de fazer com que meu site compile um código `C#`?
- Quais tecnologias eu devo usar?

O back-end está sendo feito com o [php](/questions/tagged/php), mas isso pode ser mudado conforme necessário.

Comment: A pergunta é ampla, basicamente deseja toda arquitetura de um software completo. Nem tem detalhes de como isto ocorreria. Não sei o que o WPF tem a ver com site. Acho estranho um site que vai compilar C# ser escrito em PHP. Claro que existe, tem vários funcionando e não tem nada de especial, um sistema operacional, se possível com algum tipo de isolamento, o compilador que deseja usar, no caso o [.NET Compiler platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) e o básico de uma aplicação web como outra qualquer.

Comment: @bigown Desculpe, tentei ser o mais especifico possível. Gostei do seu comentário, me ajudou a sanar muitas duvidas. Mas porque você acha que o PHP não se adequaria? O que você acha que eu deveria usar no lugar? O próprio C#? Qual seria a vantagem?

Comment: Se adequaria, mas é estranho, fica parecendo "em casa de ferreiro o espeto é de pau".

Comment: Já viu o [BOCA](https://www.ime.usp.br/~cassio/boca/) (BOCA online contest administrator)? https://github.com/cassiopc/boca/; ele é usado nas maratonas de programação aqui no Brasil, portanto trabalha com soluções _singlefile_, mas acho que pode ser um ponto de começo.

Answer (score 0):

A parte de desenhar os forms e etc, teria que ser convertido de uma estrutura para o WPF e etc, agora a parte que creio que será necessário que o servidor back-end tenha o compilador do VS instalado, ou então que ele se comunique com o um servidor Windows

Supondo que o servidor que usa PHP, então poderia usar [`exec();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

```
exec('msbuild project.sln', $ouput);

print_r($ouput);
```