# Tratamento de exceções de tipos diferentes

Tags: c#, .net, exceção

```
try {
    await DoFooAsync();
} catch (Exception e) {
    if(e is TaskCancelledException || e is UnauthorizedAccessException) {
        // ...
    }
    throw;
}
```

O bloco `catch` do trecho acima verifica o tipo da exceção capturada com um bloco condicional. Como eu farei o mesmo tratamento para `TaskCancelledException` e `UnauthorizedAcessException`, para evitar a reescrita de código com dois blocos `catch` com as mesmas chamadas, fiz da forma acima.

Entretanto, existe uma outra forma de fazer utilizando o *statement* `when`. Veja:

```
try {
    await DoFooAsync();
} catch (Exception e) when (e is TaskCancelledException || e is UnauthorizedAccessException) {
    // ...
}
```

Diferença prática não há. Até onde pude perceber os dois resultam o mesmo.

Qual é a diferença na execução dos dois? Qual é preferível e por que?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe sim, o primeiro muda o *stack trace*, o segundo não.

O primeiro intercepta a exceção lançada e lança outra exceção ali naquele local. O conteúdo pode até ser o mesmo, mas o local é diferente. O segundo mantém o *stack trace* intacto indicando a origem real do erro, então este é preferível. Conforme vai borbulhando a exceção para outros lugares poderá ver que mostra a origem em lugar diferente, o primeiro vai considerar que a exceção ocorreu ali mesmo, mas ela ocorreu antes.

Não é um recurso que será muito necessário, pelo menos se a pessoa sua exceção de forma correta, ou seja, não fica capturando qualquer coisa, mas é útil quando precisa. Foi colocado na linguagem porque o próprio [compilador do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) precisava disto para funcionar corretamente.

Um cara [respondeu no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31542237/221800) sobre isto :P

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ótima referência :P

Comment: Pode meter um exemplo no codeground (ou noutro lado qualquer) que prove que o stack trace é mudado?

Comment: @BrunoCosta é uma questão para o *debugger*, então não tem como demonstrar isto sem ser no VS ou algo assim. Dá uma lida nisto: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/541301

Comment: Entendi quando li pensei que estivesse a dizer que mudava mesmo o valor. Afinal é uma questao apenas do debugger.