# Como funciona o Edit and Continue do Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, visual-studio, edit-and-continue

O Visual Studio permite que você edite o código C#, VB.NET ou C++ em debug quando atinge um breakpoint ou clica no botão break (ícone de pausa). O nome da ferramenta é [Edit and Continue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c.aspx). De acordo a documentação

> é uma feature de produtividade que permite que você faça alterações em seu código fonte enquanto seu programa está no break mode.

Essa ferramenta não funciona para todas as edições. Mudar um [atributo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) de classe ou propriedade no C#, por exemplo, necessita parar o debug e compilar novamente. Veja em ["Supported code changes (C# and Visual Basic)"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/supported-code-changes-csharp).

Como funciona essa edição em tempo de execução? Quando edito um trecho de código, todo o projeto do arquivo editado e suas dependências são recompiladas? Ou só o trecho editado é recompilado? Existe como "recompilar" somente um método?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não tenho uma informação *autoritativa* e acho que em grande parte depende da implementação específica que pode mudar conforme a necessidade.

Em C# e VB.NET é mais ou menos fácil o código real que é executado ser gerado em tempo de execução através do [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101), então já há uma compilação na execução mesmo quando quando não usará o `Edit and Continue`. Claro que é uma compilação mais limitada, ele pega apenas um *bytecode* e gera o código executável. O JITter pode compilar só o que interessa, ele pode inclusive recompilar algo se achar que é necessário (até onde sei o .NET não faz isto, mas poderia como otimização durante a execução quando identifica um *hot path*).

Acredito que a recompilação do *bytecode* se dá apenas no método modificado, mas isto depende da implementação.

A recompilação do fonte em *bytecode* poderia ocorrer só neste método, mas tem uma chance de ser pelo menos no arquivo todo dele para verificar se tudo está certo ali naquele fonte. O [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) foi criado para poder compilar só partes de um código, até mesmo uma parte menor que um método, ainda que isto será útil em circunstâncias bem específicas.

Provavelmente há a inserção de metadados e até instruções mortas ([`nop`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)) na geração do código para facilitar a recompilação.

Feita a recompilação o JITter usará alguma estratégia para substituir o código, ou colocando na mesma área da memória (talvez até fazendo um desvio), o mais provável, ou atualizando as referências contidas em toda aplicação para o método em novo endereço.

Como já observou só é possível mudar código imperativo (com limitações), não pode mudar as estruturas de dados. Mas pode criar novas.

Em C++ uma infraestrutura maior é necessária por ele não possuir um JITter. ou seja, meio que acaba tendo que colocar um JITter na aplicação só para fazer isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).