# Como se dá a integração entre IDE e compilador?

Tags: compilação, ide, compiladores, interoperabilidade

Tirado daqui: [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101691/o-que-%C3%A9-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ide-e-compilador)

> Em geral o compilador é um programa de console, mas há casos que eles são bibliotecas que podem ser usadas em conjunto com outros programas.

A integração que acontece entre o IDE (ambiente de desenvolvimento integrado) e o compilador me deixa com dúvidas.

Quando há erros no código do usuário, o IDE precisa converter os erros reportados pelo compilador em algo amigável para montar na tela do editor de texto e mostrar ao usuário (com sublinhado vermelho/amarelo embaixo dos trechos com erro/*warning*, etc).

Quando o compilador é uma biblioteca eu imagino que é mais amigável de se fazer essa integração, mas e quando é um programa de console? Como o IDE faz para ler a informação fornecida pelo compilador?

O próprio compilador pode ser configurado para retornar os erros de uma forma mais amigável para o IDE, ou este tem que se virar para parsear toda aquela saída-padrão que o compilador mostra quando a gente tenta compilar por linha de comando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um compilador é um programa, ou seja, é um conjunto de algoritmos. A forma como ele é encapsulado para rodar em um computador importa pouco. É comum que seja uma aplicação console, mas pode ser qualquer outra coisa. Há [compiladores que foram escritos para ser primariamente uma biblioteca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) e ser usada de várias formas, console é só uma delas.

Os que não foram escritos assim, não tem uma forma específica de integração e não foi feita nenhuma adaptação, a comunicação é feita via console mesmo, ou seja, chama o executável em um outro processo passando os argumentos específicos para fazer o que deseja e captura o resultado que ele emite em console (não precisa estar mostrando na tela). É simples e tosco assim :) Ele pega o texto que sai lá, dá uma ligeira interpretada e mostra de forma conveniente do jeito que ele acha melhor.

É possível que algum compilador tenha alguma configuração que facilite alguma coisa, mas em geral não tem ou é algo bem simples, nada que vá mudar muito o resultado final. Nada impede, mas desconheço algum que seja realmente flexível, que possa ser usado pelo IDE para informações adicionais.

Alguns casos o IDE pode querer usar um compilador próprio para fazer algumas tarefas, em geral algo mais limitado e que não fará todo trabalho que o compilador de verdade faz, mas pode ser baseado nele, já que hoje quase tudo é código aberto e pode ser mexido conforme a necessidade. Mas claro que alguns são feitos do zero e o compilador é do IDE (mesmo sendo dele, não é o IDE que está fazendo o trabalho).

Esses sublinhados geralmente são feitos por este compilador interno e não pelo compilador oficial. Então costuma ser uma biblioteca, mesmo que adaptada para isto. Seria inviável ficar invocando o tempo todo um compilador completo para indicar os erros em cada coisa que você vai digitando.

Há linguagens que fornecem um servidor de linguagem onde o IDE pode se comunicar através de uma API. Não é diferente de uma biblioteca, só a forma de acesso da API é que é diferente. Eu prefiro tudo no mesmo processo.

Um dos motivos que o .NET Compiler Platform foi criado assim é justamente não ter que escrever outro compilador para cada tipo de necessidade, e é algo que outras linguagens estão fazendo, como é o [caso de Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls).

Não há uma solução única, mas o compilador padrão no console da linguagem não costuma ser usado para ajudar na edição do código. Quase todos IDEs tem seu próprio compilador de sintaxe e até semântica, mas sem otimizadores ou gerador de código, claro.